# convergence of series

Tags: time-series, covariance, convergence-divergence

Suppose that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^nk|x_k|=L<\infty.$$
Is it possible to show that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n|x_k|=K<\infty.$$
In words, does the absolute summability of $\{nx_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ imply the absolute summability of $\{x_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$?

The doubt comes from time-series. For simplicity, say that we have a mean-zero strongly stationary process $\{X_t\}_t$. It is often the case that the auto-covariance function $\gamma: \mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{R}, k\mapsto \mathbb{E}[X_{t}X_{t-k}]$ is restricted to have a controlled decay as $k$ grows large. Two (of the many) ways of achieving that are
$$\lim_{T\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^T|\gamma(k)|<\infty\qquad\text{and}\qquad \lim_{T\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^T|k\gamma(k)|<\infty, $$
where the fact that $\gamma(\cdot)$ is an even function automatically gives
$$\lim_{T\to\infty}\sum_{k=-T}^T|\gamma(k)|<\infty\qquad\text{and}\qquad \lim_{T\to\infty}\sum_{k=-T}^T|k\gamma(k)|<\infty. $$

Typically the latter is deemed as stronger, but I have never seen a formal proof nor been able to do it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is straightforward. Every single summand satisfies
$$ k|x_k| \geq |x_k| $$
(except for $k=0$, but the value of finitely many values does not have an impact on convergence of a series), so their partial sums satisfy
$$ \sum_{k=0}^n k|x_k| = \sum_{k=1}^n k|x_k|\geq \sum_{k=1}^n |x_k| $$
*for every $n>0$*, so this also holds in the limit:
$$ L-|x_0|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n k|x_k| \geq \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|. $$
And since the right hand partial sums are monotonically increasing (since all summands are nonnegative), they must converge to some $K\leq L-|x_0|$.

Comment: The first statement is not always true for $k=0$

Comment: Quite correct. This will not change the convergence itself, but of course the limit can be different, depending on $x_0$. I edited my answer.